# await Task.CompletedTask vs return

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand the difference between `await Task.CompletedTask` and `return` but can't seem to find any clearly defined explanation.

Why / when would you use this:

```cs
public async Task Test()
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

over this?

```cs
public async Task Test()
{
    return;
}
```

It's my understanding that both will have their `status` set to `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` though I have the feeling it might have to do with physical time or something like that based on the explanation from [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netcore-3.1):

> The method is commonly used when the return value of a task is immediately known without executing a longer code path.

Would appreciate a clear demystification of this as I've studied MS code on GitHub, the MS Docs as well as every link I could find but nowhere does it give a clear explanation.  I also see `await Task.CompletedTask` at the end of larger methods which per some comments I found from [MS on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/issues/2068) is actually in error as it's not supposed to contain that and they want to get it cleaned out of the repo.

If also a clear demystification of `Task.FromResult` (since they're siblings) that would be appreciated as I'm also still unclear of when to use:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Test()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

over this:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Test()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Usually, `Task.CompletedTask` and `Task.FromResult(...)` are returned, not awaited. Those allow you to implement a method returning a `Task/Task<T>` without the `async` machinery.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps.  So when you're using async/await, then you simply need to return/return the value instead of the Task?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let's look the question from the consumer-side.

If you define an interface, which imposes an operation that returns a `Task` then you don't say anything about how it will be calculated / executed (so, there is no `async` access modifier in the method signature). It is an **implementation detail**.

#### Interface

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    Task Test();
    Task<bool> IsTest();
}
```

---

So, it is up to you how you implement the interface.

You can do it in a synchronous way, when there won't be any `AsyncStateMachine` generated because of the absence of the `async` keyword.

#### Implementation #1

```cs
public class TestImpl : ITest
{
    public Task Test()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<bool> IsTest()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

---

Or you can try to implement it in an asynchronous way but without `await` operators. Here you will receive CS1998 warnings.

#### Implementation #2

```cs
public class TestImpl : ITest
{
    public async Task Test()
    {
        return;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsTest()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

In other words this implementation does not define a state machine. An async method is divided into different states based on the `await` keywords:

- before_the_await_1,
- after_the_await_1_but_before_the_await_2
- after_the_await_2_but_before_the_await_3
- ...

If you haven't got any await then you would have a single state, which would run in sync (there is no need to preserve state, execute async operation and then call `MoveNext()`).

---

Or you can try to implement it in an asynchronous way with `await` operators.

#### Implementation #3

```cs
public class TestImpl : ITest
{
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsTest()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

In this case there will be an async state machine but it won't be allocated on the heap. By default it is a `struct` and if it finishes in sync then we don't need to allocate them on the heap to extend its life out of the scope of the method.

For further information please read these articles:

- [Async/await in .NET Core 3.x](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1298139660959416320.html)
- [Async ValueTask Pooling in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-valuetask-pooling-in-net-5/)
- [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)

Comment: Am I correct to conclude that Implementation #3 is less efficient but avoids a compiler warning?

Comment: @MobyDisk Yes, correct.

Comment: @MobyDisk Let me correct myself, only the second could cause compile time warning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - yeah, I was comparing #2 and #3 really.

Comment: When targeting .NET Core, if one is choosing between 1 versus 3 for efficiency/performance, does it make any difference if it is known that the caller will definitely be async and will definitely await the calls? Would that make 3 a better choice, or is 1 always preferable?

Comment: @Mike Well basically both will run synchronously so the only difference is the generated AsyncStateMachine, which is a struct so it will add more pressure to the GC. The compiler/runtime might be smart enough to get rid of the async/await keyword... But this is micro-optimization so you should not bother too much with this IMHO

Comment: @Mike I can see the advantage of 3rd option over the 1st when you know that you will replace it soon with a real async method call.

Answer (score 9):

`return;` means you exit the function

`await Task.CompletedTask;` just continues execution of the rest of the function body.