# Return Tuple from Async Task

Tags: .net, asynchronous, tuples, task, uipath

So, I'm tried to return a Tuple from a async Task method, so I can use some information externally.
I have this method:

```
private async Task<Tuple<bool, SshClient, string>> ExecuteWithTimeout(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // Inputs
    var host = Host.Get(context);
    var user = User.Get(context);
    var password = Password.Get(context);

    bool isConnected = true;
    string message = "";

    ConnectionInfo connInfo;
    SshClient ssh;

    connInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, 22, user,
                                    new AuthenticationMethod[]
                                    {
                                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user, password)
                                    });

    ssh = new SshClient(connInfo);
    try
    {
        ssh.Connect();
        message = "SSH Connection to Baan Successfully stablished!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = "Error connecting to Baan through SSH: " + ex.Message;
        isConnected = false;
    }

    var tmp = new Tuple<bool, SshClient, string>(isConnected, ssh, message);
    return await Task.FromResult(tmp);
}
```

In the method that calls the one above, I set some output properties and return them:

```
protected override async Task<Action<AsyncCodeActivityContext>> ExecuteAsync(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Set a timeout on the execution
    var task = ExecuteWithTimeout(context, cancellationToken);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(TimeoutMS.Get(context), cancellationToken)) == task)
    {
        await task;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException(Resources.Timeout_Error);
    }

    // Outputs
    return (ctx) => {
        Connected.Set(ctx, task.Result.Item1);
        BaanConnection.Set(ctx, task.Result.Item2);
        Message.Set(ctx, task.Result.Item3);
    };
}
```

Visual Studio accepts it, compiles, publishes, but when I run it, I get this error:

> "A value of type 'System.Activities.OutArgument`1[System.Boolean]' cannot be set to the location 'Connected' because it is a location of type 'System.Boolean'.

I don't get what the problem is. I read multiple threads, tried writing this code in many different ways, trying casting, tried all things but I always get to the same point.
Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

P.S.: this project is for a UiPath Custom Activity.

Comment: How does the method look like which is calling the second snippet? Is "Connected" a out param or used in one?

Comment: I would suggest to separate `ExecuteWithTimeout`'s `Result` access from the `return` statement. `var (isConnected, ssh, message) = await task;` and then `return (ctx) => { Connected.Set(ctx, isConnected); BaanConnection.Set(ctx, ssh);    Message.Set(ctx, message); };` [Reference for Tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples)

Comment: BTW you don't need to declare your `ExecuteWithTimeout` as `async` if it is sync. Please check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885702/await-task-completedtask-vs-return/63899154#63899154) about this topic.

Comment: I edited my post to include the whole first mehtod.

Comment: For me it looks like you have a type missmatch in the code which isn't included in your sample. Try to change the Tuple to `Tuple<OutArgument<bool>, SshClient, string>`

Comment: Or change `Connected` that it can take a `bool`