# What is difference between Task.FromResult and Task.CompletedTask?

Tags: c#, task

What is difference between `Task.FromResult` and `Task.CompletedTask`?

```
public Task Test1()
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public Task Test2()
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await Task.CompletedTask vs return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885702/await-task-completedtask-vs-return)

Comment: not afew difference, i get it my answer. thanks for help.

Comment: As a side note, the `Test2()` method *does* compile. It returns `Task<int>` and `Task<T>` extends `Task`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Task.FromResult(0)` really returns a `Task<int>`, not (just) a plain `Task`.

So this would compile fine

```
 public Task<int> Test2()
 {
     return Task.FromResult(0);
 }
```

You couldn't use a Task.CompletedTask here.

---

**Late EDIT**
Another difference is that `Task.CompletedTask` is a cached value (read: no new allocation needed), while `Task.FromResult(..)` *may* need to create a new Task instance (although it tries to return a cached instance if possible, such as for `default` values).

Answer (score 2):

The `CompletedTask` has no result field, and no generic type parameter for that matter. You can use it to just skip taking system resources to do a job.

The `FromResult` variant returns a generic `Task`, with the argument's type being the generic type parameter. You can use this variant to avoid wasting resources to just return a value, in contexts where caller expects asynchronous behavior and hence requests a `Task` back.

Please note that generic `Task<T>` is deriving from non-generic `Task`, and hence both methods are equally valid in contexts where the caller makes a fire-and-forget call, or just doesn't care to read the result.

Comment: So if we just want to report the end of the task, do we use the Task .TaskComplete?

Comment: That is sufficient for a method which can return a non-generic `Task`. If that is allowed, then you are leaving the option to return a generic `Task<T>` later, and not disturb any of the existing callers who were satisfied with `Task` alone.